# R: Calculate moving maximum slope by week accounting for factors

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.frame that includes heating degree day (HDD) below.

```
structure(list(WinterID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("2002", "2002_2003", "2003", "2003_2004", 
"2004", "2004_2005", "2005", "2005_2006", "2006", "2006_2007", 
"2007", "2007_2008", "2008"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(11968, 
11969, 11970, 11971, 11972, 11973, 11974, 11975, 11976, 11977, 
11978, 11979, 11980, 11981, 11982, 11983, 11984, 11985, 11986, 
11987, 11988, 11989, 11990, 11991, 11992, 11993, 11994, 11995, 
11996, 11997, 11998, 11999, 12000, 12001, 12002, 12003, 12004, 
12005, 12006, 12007, 12008, 12009, 12010, 12011, 12012, 12013, 
12014, 12015, 12016, 12017, 12018, 12019, 12020, 12021, 12022, 
12023, 12024, 12025, 12026, 12027, 12028, 12029, 12030, 12031, 
12032, 12033, 12034, 12035, 12036, 12037, 12038, 12039, 12040, 
12041, 12042, 12043, 12044, 12045, 12046, 12047, 12048, 12049, 
12050, 12051, 12052, 12053, 12054, 12055, 12056, 12057, 12058, 
12059, 12060, 12061, 12062, 12063, 12064, 12065, 12066, 12067, 
12068, 12069, 12070, 12071, 12072, 12073, 12074, 12075, 12076, 
12077, 12078, 12079, 12080, 12081, 12082, 12083, 12084, 12085, 
12086, 12087, 12088, 12089, 12090, 12091, 12092, 12093, 12094, 
12095, 12096, 12097, 12098, 12099, 12100, 12101, 12102, 12103, 
12104, 12105, 12106, 12107, 12108, 12109, 12110, 12111, 12112, 
12113, 12114, 12115, 12116, 12117, 12118, 12119, 12120, 12121, 
12122, 12123, 12124, 12125, 12126, 12127, 12128, 12129, 12130, 
12131, 12132, 12133, 12134, 12135, 12136, 12137, 12138, 12139, 
12140, 12141, 12142, 12010, 12011, 12014, 12015, 12017, 12023, 
12024, 12025, 12026, 12027, 12028, 12029, 12030, 12042, 12070, 
12071, 12075, 12076, 12077, 12078, 12079, 12080, 12082, 12083, 
12084), class = "Date"), SiteID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "NW_SB", class = "factor"), SubstrateConcat = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("B_A", "B_B", "B_E"), class = "factor"), 
    HDD = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.246666666666667, 7.12666666666667, 10.6133333333333, 
    2.96666666666667, 0, 0.0933333333333337, 7.31333333333334, 
    10.7133333333333, 6.20000000000001, 2.70666666666667, 6.20000000000001, 
    3.88666666666667, 16.5866666666667, 28.3933333333333, 12.98, 
    21.6133333333333, 19.14, 12.6666666666667, 7.52, 3.33333333333334, 
    18.2933333333333, 4.14666666666667, 2.17333333333334, 26.08, 
    1.38, 7.48000000000001, 36.5733333333333, 53.4666666666667, 
    98.4533333333333, 109.093333333333, 104.14, 80.2466666666667, 
    47.0333333333333, 14.7133333333333, 15.7266666666667, 21.1066666666667, 
    5.07333333333334, 0.613333333333334, 6.18000000000001, 29.5666666666667, 
    45.5333333333333, 59.5666666666667, 91.44, 85.38, 51.1, 25.9666666666667, 
    14.8266666666667, 34.48, 79.16, 90.08, 66.3533333333333, 
    75.14, 97.1733333333333, 83.3066666666667, 50.0133333333333, 
    37.2733333333333, 88.9133333333334, 101.926666666667, 100.56, 
    99.2933333333334, 97.66, 89.6466666666667, 110.613333333333, 
    79.1466666666667, 92.6066666666667, 71.7133333333333, 31.32, 
    27.02, 39.02, 98.14, 62.5866666666667, 46.7933333333333, 
    47.5133333333333, 48.3666666666667, 25.5333333333333, 13.6, 
    17.9133333333333, 14.16, 7.98666666666667, 3.44, 1.86666666666667, 
    12.66, 0, 7.09333333333334, 21.3266666666667, 40.52, 18.8466666666667, 
    37.8466666666667, 33.42, 33.7133333333333, 15.6133333333333, 
    0.720000000000001, 2.31333333333334, 12.3066666666667, 8.48666666666667, 
    2.86, 0, 0, 0, 6.98666666666667, 6.67333333333334, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.58000000000001, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13.42, 30.5266666666667, 
    1.12, 28.5066666666667, 6.82666666666667, 10.3933333333333, 
    3.18, 11.0466666666667, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("WinterID", 
"Date", "SiteID", "SubstrateConcat", "HDD"), row.names = c(NA, 
200L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to calculate the moving maximum slope over 7 days beginning on 4 November of each year without using a loop. This moving maximum slope needs to account for WinterID, SiteID, and SubstrateConcat.

For clarification, the calculation I'm trying to obtain is this:

```
Slope=(max-min)/7, where:
Max= (i-3)+(i-2)+(i-1)+i+(i+1)+(i+2)+(i+3) 
Min= (i-3)

(((i-3)+(i-2)+(i-1)+i+(i+1)+(i+2)+(i+3)) - (i-3))/7
```

So, using a real example starting with 2002-11-19 as i:

```
(0+0.24+7.13+10.61+2.97+0+0.97) - 0)/7 = 3.13
```

I tried using `zoo` package `rollmean`, however, I could not figure out how to account for WinterID, SiteID, and SubstrateConcat. This gave me an "order.by" error where my Date values were not unique, since I have dates with different SubstrateConcat and WinterID criteria. As I enter more data into the database, there will eventually be dates with multiple SiteID criteria as well.

I thought maybe `xts`, `TTR` and `ROC` would be what I could use as in this question: [Maximum slope for a given interval each day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552200/maximum-slope-for-a-given-interval-each-day). But again, I don't understand how to specify the multiple group factors, as well as going three days forward and three days back as in align=center with rollmean.

Will someone please point me in the right direction here? Will one of the above functions combined with `ddply` work?

### Thank you!

EDITED to include the answer after the answer supplied by @eddi.

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, MaxSlope := if(length(HDD)<7) {rep(NA_real_, length(HDD))} else {filter(HDD, c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0)/7)}, by=list(Winter, Site, Substrate)]
```

This code works perfectly for dates that are continuous. Can anyone recommend how to tweak this code for data that has missing dates? For instance, I have:

```
   Date  Temp 
 Nov 21  14 
 Nov 23  10 
 Nov 24  12 
 Nov 27  11 
 Nov 28  7 
 Nov 29  9 
 Nov 30  10 
 Dec 01  12 
 Dec 02  8  
 Dec 03  7
```

I don't want the Max Slope calculated for Nov 21, Nov 23 and Nov 24 because there isn't consecutive data for the calculation. Instead, I want "NA" inserted. Can the existing code above, be modified to accommodate this?

Comment: @naomik Hardly a downvote reason imo...

Comment: If it's going to be a long code paste, at least try formatting it. From the looks of it though, you've done nothing to try to reduce the size of the code paste or isolate your problem.

Comment: @naomik: The OP was providing the reproducible data. I think you misunderstood the `dput` with the long code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need `filter` (or you could also use one of the rolling mean/sum functions). And the grouping part is easiest to do with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(your_df)

dt[, filter(HDD, c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0))/7,
     by = list(WinterID, SiteID, SubstrateConcat)]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what filter is doing? I thought filter() was another way of subsetting. I don't exactly understand the "c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0))/7 is doing. Is it calculating the sum and dividing by 7? I need the Slope, which is (Max-Min)/7.  <br/>Also, with the above code, I see that I can specify "sides=2" to get forward and backward of middle value. But, how do I specify what the middle value should be? For instance, if I want the window to start at 4 November so that my window is 1 November (3 back) to 7 November (3 forward), how do I do that?

Comment: `RBD.DT[, filter(HDD, c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0))/7,
       by=list(WinterID, SiteID, SubstrateConcat)]`  
Error in filter(HDD, c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)) : 
  'filter' is longer than time series

Comment: @BgnR see Details section of `?filter` to see what it does - in this case it just adds `(i-2)+(i-1)+i+(i+1)+(i+2)+(i+3)` as per OP; that error simply means that you have a subgroup that has less than 7 elements - e.g. `filter(c(1,2,3), c(1,1,1,1,1,1))` - you can add an `if` to account for that and take whatever action you like, e.g.: `dt[, if (length(HDD) < 7) { rep(NA_real_, length(HDD))} else {filter...}, ...]`.

Comment: is c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0) calling on the first value of HDD in the data.table? How do I know what value the code starts with?

Comment: @BgnR sorry, I don't understand your question - best thing to do (after reading the documentation) to understand what `filter` does it to experiment with simple examples, e.g. `filter(c(1:10), c(1,1,0))`

Comment: I read the documentation on filter before I asked my first question about it. I'll do some more experimenting with it. Thanks. 

I also don't understand what rep(NA_real_, ...) does. And I have looked at documentation on rep and NA_real_.

Comment: `NA_real_` is the real version of `NA`, which I used to be explicit that it's not a logical `NA` (the default, when you just type `NA`); `rep` just repeats that `NA` `length(HDD)` times

Comment: I ended up not using data.table. After reading all of the data.table documentation and posts on SO with [data.table] tags, I couldn't figure out how to get the calculation inserted back into the data.table or data.frame instead of just printing in the Console window. Therefore, I used this: `dt$MaxSlope <- if (length(dt$HDD) < 7) {rep(NA_real_, length(dt$HDD))} else {filter(dt$HDD, c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0)/7)} by=list(dt$WinterID, dt$SiteID, dt$SubstrateConcat)`. The calculations are great but I cannot get the `by` statement to work. Can you please show me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: @BgnR use `dt[, newcol := ...]` to add that column to your `data.table`

Comment: @BgnR that expression doesn't make sense semantically, so I'm not sure what insight to offer - the `by` in `data.table` is an argument of `[.data.table` and is not smth that can be used outside

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you :) So, now I have this code, but keep getting errors due to syntax. `dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, newcol = if (length(HDD) < 7) {rep(NA_real_, length(HDD))} else {filter(HDD, c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0))/7, by=list(WinterID, SiteID, SubstrateConcat)}]` I keep getting "unexpected ',' or unexpected symbol.

Comment: @BgnR you forgot the `:`, i.e. `dt[, newcol := ...`; and also have a misplaced `}`

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get working solution with `ddply`, though I didn't spend much time debugging.  Here's a solution using base functions (assuming your object is named `hdd`).

```
# split your object into groups
shdd <- split(hdd, hdd[,c("WinterID","SiteID","SubstrateConcat")], drop=TRUE)
# create a function to apply to each group
f <- function(d) transform(d, MaxSlopeHDD=rollmax(c(NA,diff(d$HDD)),7,fill=NA))
# apply the function to each group and rbind the results together
shdd <- do.call(rbind, lapply(shdd, f))
```